# Django application can access DB models but Pytest can't (invalid object name)

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-models, pytest

I'm using Pytest to write unit tests for a Django application. The application itself has no issue working with its databases, and it can read and write data completely fine with any method. When testing, database access using a cursor object works totally fine as well. However, whenever I try to access one of the databases in a test via a model object, I get this error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name '<table I'm trying to access>'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Here's a minimal test that causes this issue - it produces the error above, using the table name `Students_with_Holds`:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db(databases=['Coursematch'])
def test_db_access(self):
    testobj = StudentsWithHolds.objects.using('Coursematch').create(
        person_id_number = 'testPIDnum',
        hold_type_code = 'test'
    )
    assert testobj.person_id_number == 'testPIDnum'
    assert testobj.hold_type_code == 'test'
```

Attempting to perform the exact same procedure using a cursor object, as shown below, does not cause the issue:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db(databases=['Coursematch'])
def test_db_access_cursor(self):
    with connections['Coursematch'].cursor() as cursor:
        insert_query = """
        INSERT INTO Coursematch.dbo.Students_with_Holds (person_id_number,hold_type_code)
        VALUES ('testPIDnum','test')
        """
        cursor.execute(insert_query)
        check_query = """
        SELECT person_id_number,hold_type_code
        FROM Coursematch.dbo.Students_with_Holds
        WHERE person_id_number = 'testPIDnum'
        """
        cursor.execute(check_query)
        assert cursor.fetchone() == ('testPIDnum','test')
```

Any suggestions on how to stop this from happening? I've made sure that my models are all migrated, that everything used in the code is being imported, and that the tables and classes I'm using all have the correct names (the name difference between `StudentsWithHolds` and `Students_with_Holds` is because the first is a model class and the second is the actual DB table). Online tutorials suggest that there should be no issues with using model objects in tests, so I really have no idea what's going on.

Comment: SQL server is a pain, I know this. Pytest creates its own empty database prior to running tests - it's prefixed `test_` and then whatever your usual db is (for me it's pretty much always `test_postgres`. Could it be it doesn't have permissions tocreate a db in your SQL server setup?

Comment: It's definitely able to create the test DB, the creation shows up in the logs for my MSSQL server. Also, if the test DB wasn't being created, wouldn't that make the cursor method fail as well?